How to set a colour for basic HTML elements with angular material's m3 theme?
So, prior to m3, I used a reboot scss file to set an empty base that's equal in all browsers, which I just grabbed from the web somewhere.
Since this file used a couple variables, I turned it into a mixin, into which I passed my theme like this:
@mixin theme($theme) {
  $typography-config: mat.get-typography-config($theme);
  $color-config: mat.get-color-config($theme);

  $base-palette: map.get($color-config, background);
  $primary-palette: map.get($color-config, primary);
  $accent-palette: map.get($color-config, accent);

  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: mat.font-family($typography-config, body-1);
    font-size: mat.font-size($typography-config, body-1);
    font-weight: mat.font-weight($typography-config, body-1);
    line-height: mat.line-height($typography-config, body-1);
    color: mat.get-color-from-palette($base-palette, 50);
    text-align: left;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, mat.get-color-from-palette($base-palette, 400), mat.get-color-from-palette($base-palette, 600)); // 2
  }

  a {
    color: mat.get-color-from-palette($accent-palette, 500);
    background-color: transparent; // Remove the gray background on active links in IE 10.

    @include hover() {
      color: mat.get-color-from-palette($accent-palette, 300);
  }

  ...
}

Then I would call this mixin in my _theme.scss
@use './reboot' as reboot;

...

@include mat.all-component-themes($wb-theme);
@include mat.core($wb-typography-config);
@include reboot.theme($wb-theme);

...

But now this crashes with the error:
X [ERROR] Undefined function.
   ╷
47 │   $typography-config: mat.get-typography-config($theme);

At first the typography only showed up on material elements but was missing for plain HTML, like a text with a paragraph. I was able to fix the background colour by placing my app contents inside the navbar content element, and the typography by including the typography hierarchy.
...

html {
  @include mat.core-theme(theme.$dark-theme);
  @include mat.all-component-themes(theme.$dark-theme);
  @include mat.typography-hierarchy(theme.$dark-theme);
}

...

However, this still doesn't solve all my issues. If I add a link to the paragraph, that shoes up in default browser colours for links, i.e. #0000ff and with an underline. Of course I'd like to restyle that as well to fit the theme of my application.
From what I get is that m3 basically only uses css variables like:
.mat-mdc-tab-link .mdc-tab__text-label { 
  color: var(--mat-tab-header-inactive-label-text-color);
  ...
}

However, the variable the link receives is color: -webkit-link;, which is not set by the theme at all, so I have to actually give it the value I need, or change the value of the attribute itself but for either case, I need to set an actual colour. I'm fine with using variables but how do I set one and give it a colour of my theme?
This also isn't just an issue of the link or some basic HTML elements. I had restyled all material elements to fit the app, each with their own .scss file with a mixin in it that takes the theme and extracts the colours I need to set, create gradients and colours where there are none in the original material element, so I really need to make some quite significant changes and do require the colours to set them for whatever I need (directly or to create some variables. How do I do this with m3?

Have you changed your theme to m3 or is it still an m2 theme? M3 themes have no accent color and there are different ways to handle things if you're legacy or not.

you can generate a "correct" m3 theme with this command : ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme

@Grogu Yes, it is an m3 theme. I know they don't have "accent" colours anymore, but it doesn't matter to me whether they're called primary/accent or primary/secondary/tertiary/neutral/etc., they're still palettes, which I need access to. I'm also uncertain as to what legacy is, all I can find is a styling of form input, which I didn't use, so I guess I'm not legacy.

@ChristopheLeBesnerais I did use this command. How does this answer my question?

Because we are missing half the info to be able to help you. Half migrated theme and m3 theme don't have the same keys and ways to handle things. If you have "accent" somewhere in your theme/palette definition, then you are still in m2 (to makes things easy).

To set typography for html tags, you need to have the css class "mat-typography" set in your html (supposed to be set on the body). Also to access m3 colors, you can use get-theme-color with palette or role https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#reading-tonal-palette-colors and https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#reading-color-roles . To access typography use get-theme-typography https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#reading-typescale-properties

You're right, you can configure things setting custom values to material css variables. I'm not sure if anchors are colored now, even with material classes, but you can customize it yourself with something as   a:link {
color: mat.get-theme-color($theme, primary, 50);
} and you need to do that for each anchor state

you can add a background to the app with the class mat-app-background https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#application-background-color

@Grogu What info do you need? I created an m3 theme and I need access to its palettes. What more info is there you require? It's an m3 theme, and it has palettes, and I need to extract them from the m3 theme to put them in a variable and extract the colours out of it. I haven't "migrated" anything.

@Grogu mat.get-theme-color($theme, primary, 50); Yes, this is what I needed. Thanks. If you want to reply this as an answer I can mark it.

We were* missing info (fully migrated m3 theme or not)

@Grogu What do you even mean with "fully migrated". I've created an m3 theme and used my custom _reboot.scss as I had it set up for m2 (which obviously didn't work). The m3 theme is the m3 theme. I don't understand what information you want there.

As you are using a m3 theme fully migrated:
To set typography for html tags, you need to have the css class mat-typography set in your html (supposed to be set on the body).
Also to access m3 colors, you can use get-theme-color with palette https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#reading-tonal-palette-colors or role https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#reading-color-roles
To access typography use get-theme-typography https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#reading-typescale-properties
You can add a background to the app with the class mat-app-background https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#application-background-color

Thanks. I already had mat-typography set on the body tag, but it still didn't work for links (and who else knows what other tags don't work, that was the first thing I tested). Setting mat-app-background as class won't do it for me, as I'm using a slight gradient as background, which the theme doesn't inherently offer, so I need to define that myself using the theme colors but thanks for the tip anyway.

I can't find link color in the v3 material specification, when it was specified as accent color for m2. Specs are evolving, I guess that it has been removed. Angular material is implementing material specs, so this is the new expected behavior
